# Getting incorrect answer for ULP error of double

Tags: floating-point

I am learning about ULP errors for double. I am looking at an example where the exact and the computed values are:

```
exact: 0|01111100010|1110101100000111111001001001011110001000000000111110
compt: 0|01111100010|1110101100000111111001001001011110001000000001000100
```

The answer for ULP of this is 6 ULP. I can't quite see how that's the case. Between 0111110 and 1000100, I can only count 5 doubles:

```
0111110 - start
0111111 - 1
1000000 - 2
1000001 - 3
1000010 - 4
1000011 - 5
1000100 - end
```

I think I'm making some very simple mistake here. Any pointers?

Comment: Replace "start" with 0 and "end" with 6 and there is the answer.

Comment: Quang, Consider the case of `0111110 - start` and `0111111 - 1`. What is the ULP difference:  1 or 0?

Comment: @njuffa ah... I see...

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it should be 1 in your provided case. This makes it clearer for me now - thanks! Feel free to turn it into an answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: @QuangThinhHa Perhaps better to  [post your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I made a mistake when doing the count. It should be:

```
0111110 - 0
0111111 - 1
1000000 - 2
1000001 - 3
1000010 - 4
1000011 - 5
1000100 - 6 <---------- the expected answer.
```